# Problems with ASP.NET MVC site as an application in IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I've got an MVC project that I just installed as an application on an existing IIS Site.  When testing, routing works just fine because it's running at the root of localhost, but when I deploy it as an application routing gets messed up (it's trying to route any methods to http://foo.com/search instead of http://foo.com/bar/search).  I know this should be a fairly simple thing to fix, I just can't seem to come up with the correct wording that google seems to like.
FWIW, I tried doing the following, but it started throwing 403 errors:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "bar/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Originally that URL was "{controller}/{action}/{id}" instead of "site/...".

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you made sure you are calling `Url.Content("~/")` instead of just `"~/"` in your get/post calls?

Comment: That did it.  I'm pretty new to MVC and was just putting in straight URLs instead of doing Url.Content.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. I reposted my comment as an answer so you could check it as preferred answer (if it helped you of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are calling `Url.Content("~/")` instead of just `"~/"` in your get/post calls.

I had this problem on some of my mvc projects before so I figured that was what was happening.

Good luck!

(If it's not okay to post my comment as an answer I will remove this)

Comment: I'm ok with it, I was just waiting for you to write an answer so I could mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to separate some modules into some other sub-folder structure. Have you tried using Areas?

It is not easy to just use an existing url to re-route.

Instead try a Mouse Right click on your VS 2010 project and add an Area. All the controllers and views which come under the area will fall into a subfolder. For example I have a url which is like http://localhost:4000/admin/manageuser/add

Comment: The parent site and the mvc app are in two different projects.  They only come together in the production environment.  I will look into this in the future though.  Turns out I was using straight URLs instead of Url.Content as Evan Layman said in the comment to my post.